# How to check `typeof` for void value at compile time?

Tags: c, types, void, c-preprocessor, compile-time

let's say that I want to have C macro that works on any type.
I'm using GCC compiler (>= 4.6) and can use GNU99 macros.

```
//code...
any_type_t *retVal = function_that_runs_very_long_time(a, b, &&c, **d, &e, *f);
//other code...
```

usage of macro for TIMER can look for example like this

```
//code...
any_type_t *retVal = 
    TIMER(
          function_that_runs_very_long_time(a, b, &&c, **d, &e, *f),
          "TIMING FOR VALUE <%d, %d>", a, b
         );
//other code...
```

So TIMER has to return value of given function and print duration of its run.
There is problem with functions that have `void` return type.

I can obviously have two macros like TIMER_TYPE and TIMER_VOID, but I want to use single one to time function with any return value.

Thank you for suggestions.

---

Edited example of this TIMER macro

```
#define TIMER(expr, fmt_msg, ...)                           \
({                                                          \
    struct timeval before, after;                           \
    uint64_t time_span;                                     \
    int time_span_sec, time_span_usec;                      \
    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);                            \
    typeof(expr) _timer_expr__ = (expr);                    \ // <- static if?
    gettimeofday(&after, NULL);                             \
    time_span = (after.tv_sec * 1000000 + after.tv_usec)    \
              - (before.tv_sec * 1000000 + before.tv_usec); \
    time_span_sec  = time_span / 1000000;                   \
    time_span_usec = time_span % 1000000;                   \
    TRACE(fmt_msg "\n%s : %d.%d seconds",                   \
          #expr, time_span_sec, time_span_usec, ...);       \
    _timer_expr__;                                          \
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible in C. I had a similar question in C++, which required a C++-only approach. If you're interested, it's [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625526/check-at-compile-time-if-template-argument-is-void).

Comment: Thanks, Chris, but I'm limited to C(99) only. I've actually read (not only) your post before posting this question. :)

Comment: Macros can't "return" values. You may be able to simulate it by using the comma operator though.

Comment: macros CAN return values while using GCC extensions, look at definition of TIMER macro, it returns value of type which is return type of (expr)

Comment: Joachim: You can even declare LAMBDA macro and use it as
qsort(arr, n, size, LAMBDA(int, (x, y) { x>y }); viz http://stackoverflow.com/a/3326424/64062

Comment: How about using the `-finstrument-functions` option in gcc? [demonstration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-graphvis/).

Comment: Alexey: Thanks, this is great stuff, I will definitely use it as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What an interesting question, kudos!

After few experiments, I found a solution which uses [`__builtin_types_compatible_p` and `__builtin_choose_expr`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) intrinsics of GCC.

### `__builtin_types_compatible_p`

Quoting GCC manual:

> Built-in Function: `int __builtin_types_compatible_p (type1, type2)`
>
> You can use the built-in function `__builtin_types_compatible_p` to determine whether two types are the same.
>
> This built-in function returns `1` if the unqualified versions of the types `type1` and `type2` (which are types, not expressions) are compatible, `0` otherwise. **The result of this built-in function can be used in integer constant expressions.**
>
> This built-in function ignores top level qualifiers (e.g., `const`, `volatile`). For example, `int` is equivalent to `const int`.

So here is how we can check for "`void`ness".

```
#define __type_is_void(expr) __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(expr), void)
```

### `__builtin_choose_expr`

> Built-in Function: `type __builtin_choose_expr (const_exp, exp1, exp2)`
>
> You can use the built-in function `__builtin_choose_expr` to evaluate code depending on the value of a constant expression. This built-in function returns `exp1` if `const_exp`, which is an integer constant expression, is nonzero. Otherwise it returns `exp2`.
>
> This built-in function is analogous to the `? :` operator in C, except that **the expression returned has its type unaltered by promotion rules. Also, the built-in function does not evaluate the expression that is not chosen**. For example, if `const_exp` evaluates to true, `exp2` is not evaluated even if it has side-effects.
>
> **If `exp1` is returned, the return type is the same as `exp1`'s type. Similarly, if `exp2` is returned, its return type is the same as `exp2`.**

So `__builtin_choose_expr` intrinsic is something like a "static switch" evaluated at compile-time.

### Preparation

I don't paste here your `TIMER` macro, but I assume it is able to split it into two versions: one for void `expr` and one for the rest. Here are just stubs which evaluate the expression and yield the result of the same type.

```
#define __DO(expr) \
    ({ typeof(expr) __ret; __ret = (expr); __ret; })

#define __DO_VOID(expr) \
    (void) (expr)
```

### Naive solution

Now we can statically switch between two implementations, depending on the actual type of the expression. But in fact the naive solution doesn't work, see below.

```
#define DO(expr) \
    __builtin_choose_expr(__type_is_void(expr), \
        __DO_VOID(expr), \
        __DO(expr))  # won't work
```

Attempt to compile this code passing a void expression gives the following error:

```
test.c:28:9: error: variable or field ‘__ret’ declared void
test.c:28:9: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Although `__DO_VOID` is chosen, `__DO` generates errors. This behavior is described in manual:

> ... the unused expression (`exp1` or `exp2` depending on the value of `const_exp`) may still generate syntax errors. This may change in future revisions.

### Working solution

The trick is to substitute the original void `expr` with some non-void value to be able to compile the `__DO` case (which is anyway a dead code when `expr` is void).

```
#define __expr_or_zero(expr) __builtin_choose_expr(__type_is_void(expr), 0, (expr))

#define DO(expr) \
    __builtin_choose_expr(__type_is_void(expr), \
        __DO_VOID(expr), \
        __DO(__expr_or_zero(expr))) # works fine!
```

That's it! Here is the complete source code on Ideone: http://ideone.com/EFy4pE

Comment: Hey. I just tested it now. This is crazy, it works. I love you man. :-)

Answer (score 2):

can you accept an answer of "this isn't really possible" ?

not the part about returning from a macro.  but the part about conditionally testing expr for its return type.

in effect, you're asking for something like the following:

let's say instead of some magical check called "is_expr_type_void(expr)", you instead simply pass a 1 or a 0 at the time of the call to indicate is_void or !is_void in the following variation of your macro:

```
#define TIMER(is_void, expr, fmt_msg, ...)                  \
({                                                          \
    struct timeval before, after;                           \
    uint64_t time_span;                                     \
    int time_span_sec, time_span_usec;                      \
    gettimeofday(&before, NULL);                            \
    if (is_void)                                            \
        (expr)                                              \
    else                                                    \
        typeof(expr) _timer_expr__ = (expr);                \ // <- static if?
    gettimeofday(&after, NULL);                             \
    time_span = (after.tv_sec * 1000000 + after.tv_usec)    \
              - (before.tv_sec * 1000000 + before.tv_usec); \
    time_span_sec  = time_span / 1000000;                   \
    time_span_usec = time_span % 1000000;                   \
    TRACE(fmt_msg "\n%s : %d.%d seconds",                   \
          #expr, time_span_sec, time_span_usec, ...);       \
    if (!is_void)                                           \
        _timer_expr__;                                      \
})
```

this simply cannot work. the preprocessor would create code for that if-else conditional in all cases, both void and non-void function calls.  and both sides would compile fine for non-void functions.  but the compiler would always choke on the "else" part of the conditional when TIMER is invoked with a void function … despite the fact that the code would never be called.

(now if there existed a really smart compiler that could both identify that it would be dead code and dead-strip it prior to flagging it as a compile time error, you'd be in luck!  but i don't think gcc 4.6 is that smart … )

this leaves you with what would be a preferred option of a #if (is_void) conditional inside the #define.  but that's simply not allowed. since, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/301889/774691) points out in attempting to answer a similar question about conditional preprocessing, the preprocessor is not [turing-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness).

so … despite your desire to have a single macro, i think your simplest answer is to create one for void functions, and one for functions with return values.

Comment: Yes, John, this kind of reasoning is what I come up too. I already have it as two macros, just hoped that someone will magically resolve this by means that are unknown to me. But Your answer is correct and you deserve a bounty... :-)

Comment: Here is my solution for GCC which uses a single macro: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15448781/545027

Answer (score 2):

As long as you've got `typeof` and `_Generic`, you can do also do it without `__builtin_types_compatible_p` or `__builtin_choose_expr`.

The caveat is that `_Generic` won't let you match `void` so instead of matching `Expr` against `void`, match `(typeof(Expr)*){0}` against `void*`.

Below is [eldar-abusalimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/545027/eldar-abusalimov) example modified to use `_Generic` instead of `__builtin_types_compatible_p` and `__builtin_choose_expr`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define __type_is_void(expr) _Generic((typeof(expr)*){0}, void*:1, default:0)
#define __expr_or_zero(expr) _Generic((typeof(expr)*){0}, void*:0, default:(expr))

#define DO(expr) \
    _Generic((typeof(expr)*){0}, \
        void*:__DO_VOID(expr), \
        default:__DO(__expr_or_zero(expr)))

#define __DO(expr) \
    ({ typeof(expr) __ret; puts("do nonvoid"); __ret = (expr); __ret; })

#define __DO_VOID(expr) \
    (void)({ puts("do void"); (void)(expr); })

void foo(void) { }
int bar(void) { return 1; }

int main(void) 
{
    DO(foo());
    DO(bar());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The __type_is_void macro is not actually needed in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to return from macro, use **inline** function instead.

Comment: Returning from macro is not a problem. Problem is to NOT return (resp. to "save" value of type void).