# Macro conditional statements in C

Tags: c, macros, conditional-statements, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to implement a macro conditional inside a macro function in C. Something like this:

```
#define fun(x)
#if x==0
    fun1;
#else
    fun2;
#endif

#define fun1 // do something here
#define fun2 // do something else here
```

In other words, preprocessor decides which macro to use based on an argument value.

```
fun(0) // fun1 is "preprocessed"
fun(1) // fun2 is "preprocessed"
```

I know that this example doesn't work, but I want to know is it possible to make it work somehow?

M.

Comment: The pre-processor "modifies" the code *even before compilation*, so at runtime is definitely settled.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But `x` is not a variable, it's value is known before compilation.

Comment: [BOOST_PP_IF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/if.html) (or IIF)

Comment: I don't think that's possible. The C preprocessor is pretty limited in its functionality. I like to use GNU m4, which is very powerful. Unfortunately, its development is somehow stuck, I don't know about future releases (if there ever will be one). With cpp, I'd just define a value `x` as you did, but put the conditional directives outside of a macro.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot use pre-processor conditionals inside a pre-processor directive. Background and workarounds you find for example here: [How to use #if inside #define in the C preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2831934/694576) and [Is it possible for C preprocessor macros to contain preprocessor directives?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/301711/694576)

Still, you *could* do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CONCAT(i) fun ## i() /* For docs on this see here:
                                https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html */
#define fun(i) CONCAT(i)

void fun1(void)
{
  puts(__FUNCTION__);
}

void fun2(void)
{
  puts(__FUNCTION__);
}


int main(void)
{
  fun(1);
  fun(2);
}
```

This would result in:

```
...

int main(void)
{
  fun1();
  fun2();
}
```

being passed to the compiler and print:

```
fun1
fun2
```

---

You could obfuscate your code even more by doing for example:

```
... 

#define MYZERO 1
#define MYONE 2

int main(void)
{
  fun(MYZERO);
  fun(MYONE);
}
```

resulting in the same code being passed to the compiler.

Comment: Upvoted and deleted my answer, but it would be useful (for others) to explain why `#if` 'inside' `#define` doesn't work.

Comment: Good solution, but why on earth is your token-pasting macro named "stringify" ? ;)

Comment: @Quentin: Hu, habbits and patterns ... :} fixing this.

Comment: Dear alk, thank you for your answers. I have one more question regarding macros. Is it possible to get something like this - Macro function is called as `macro_fun(7)`, and the output is `AD1`. In other words, I want to evaluate `7-6`, and to concatenate the result as a token, e.g. `AD ## x-6`. I know that this example doesn't work, but can I make it work somehow?

Comment: @Marko: I am not aware that the pre-processor does any arithmetics, will say evaluates 3-2 to 1 or such. Perhaps you want to read on functions-pointers and handle all this mapping at run-time in C.

Comment: @abligh I suspect this is because the `#if`-statement is evaluated when the macro is defined and not when the macro is called.